# getting file not found error while reading zip file entry

Tags: c#

I have a file `1.txt` inside zip file `1.zip` which content are base64 encoded, now I am trying to read bytes `FromBase64String` as a zip entry, but getting error file not found. Do I need to extract and then read?

```
   using (var zipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(@"C:\tmp\1.zip"))
            {
                foreach (var entry in zipArchive.Entries.Where(e => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Name)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(entry.Name);

                    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(File.ReadAllText(entry.FullName));

                }
            }
```

> Could not find file 'C:\repos\net452\net452\bin\Debug\1.txt'.

Comment: `File.ReadAllText(entry.FullName)` -> reads from the _file system_. I know Windows masks a lot of it these days, but the contents of a zip file is not part of the file system, it's part of the zip file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current issue is that you're using `File.ReadAllText`, which reads from the file system, not the contents of the zip file.

You need to read from *within the zip file*. You can do this by opening the entry's stream. To read it as text, you can use a `StreamReader`:

```
using (var zipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(@"C:\tmp\1.zip"))
{
    foreach (var entry in zipArchive.Entries.Where(e => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Name)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Name);

        byte[] bytes = null;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(entry.Open()))
        {
            bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot John. Appreciate!